# Helm template kubernetes service with multiple ports

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have kubernetes service exposing 2 ports that I want to manage with helm :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myproject-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: myproject-web
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8181
  - name: myproject-tcp
    port: 61616
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 61616
  selector:
    app: myproject-dev
```

I created a kubernetes-helm template :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.project }}-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: {{ .Values.project }}-web
    port: {{ .Values.serviceweb.port }}
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: {{ .Values.serviceweb.targetPort }}
  - name: {{ .Values.project }}-tcp
    port: {{ .Values.servicetcp.port }}
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: {{ .Values.servicetcp.targetPort }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.project }}-{{ .Values.environment }}
```

And in my `values.yaml` :

```
project: activemq

serviceweb:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8161

servicetcp:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 61616
```

When I execute a dry-run command, it seems helm is not happy if `.Values.service` is not defined :

```
helm install --dry-run --set environment=dev --name myproject --debug myproject/;

Error: render error in "myproject/templates/NOTES.txt": template: myproject/templates/NOTES.txt:8:39: executing "myproject/templates/NOTES.txt" at <.Values.service.type>: can't evaluate field type in type interface {}
```

I saw the `.Values.service` is also referred in `templates/tests/test-connection.yaml`. These files contains the original values after their generation with `helm create` command.

Is there an elegant way to create a helm template for service with multiple port ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error I guess in NOTES.txt , you are referring type as `.Values.service.type`. This will fail as in values.yaml the root object for type is `serviceweb` or `servicetcp`.

You might need to replace the line as `.Values.serviceweb.type` or `.Values.servicetcp.type` as per your use case and then try.

Comment: Indeed, the error can be solved by editing the NOTES.txt but my problem was in fact (see my answer above) broader

Answer (score 0):

My question comes from a poor knowledge of helm. Many files are optionnal in the helm chart file structure and NOTES.txt is one of them.

When you start with `helm create` like me, it creates a directory structure (with optionnal files), pre-configure a deployment, service and ingress templates and default values in values.yaml. If you need somehting more specific like me with my 2 services ports, you need to edit the template, the values.yaml and all the files where the single service port is refered. If these files are optionnal, you can also simply remove them.